# Java long to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, types

What is the equivalent of Java `long` in the context of MySQL *data types*?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

[`SIGNED BIGINT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html) is a 8-bytes long integer just like Java's `long`.

Comment: Note that in MySQL all `INT` types are signed by default.

Answer (score 22):

Java long max value is positive: `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`

This means for positive only unsigned numbers `UNSIGNED BIGINT(19)` should be enough or you can just use `UNSIGNED BIGINT` which is equal to `UNSIGNED BIGINT(20)`

If you are going to use negative numbers as well `BIGINT(19)` will be enough.