# Simple program throws ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am doing a simple program to connect MySQL database with Java, but the program throws the ClassCastException error.

[Java long to MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781218/java-long-to-mysql)

This question says that Unsigned Bigint in MySQL is equivalent to long in Java.

Given below is the java part:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///check1","uname","pwd");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from t1");
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getObject(1)+ " "+ rs.getObject(2));
    }
    rs.close();
    st.close();
    con.close();
}
```

I am also including the schema for the table I created

```
mysql> desc t1;                                                                                                                                                         
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+                                                                                                        
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |                                                                                                        
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+                                                                                                        
| rollno | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |                                                                                                        
| name   | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |                                                                                                        
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+                                                                                                        
2 rows in set (0.39 sec)
```

Comment: Have you checked this? [bigint in mysql to java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998896/mysql-bigint-conversion-to-java-long)

Comment: Where is the code that throws your exception?

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace

Comment: Its the big int you have to get its long value in java. 
But still the stacktrace would be helpful to confirm

Comment: I'm really sorry I forgot to post the full stacktrace it totally slipped my mind.
Also, @LukeWoodward thanks, your link helped. The problem was the JDBC connector I was using. Using the latest version solved the problem.
Thanks for your help everyone

Answer (score -2):

Try to do this way

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Comment: That is entirely unnecessary and will not solve the problem. It was once (15+ years ago) necessary with a buggy version of the predecessor of MySQL Connector/J to get it to register (because they had put the driver registration in an instance initializer and not in a static initializer). And using `Class.forName` itself is not even necessary in this case (and hasn't been for 10+ years), assuming the OP is using a JDBC 4 compliant driver.

Comment: If the driver had not been loaded correctly, the OP would have received a `SQLException` with the "No suitable driver" exception message.